# Trying to parse HTML returned by Post request

Tags: c#

I'm trying to parse this endpoint.  It returns an html page.   I am able to call it on Postman with no parameters and no content setting.   Here I get a "Not acceptable" status.  Is RestSharp suitable for this call?  Am I leaving something out?

```
        var client = new RestClient("endpoint_url");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Are you sure it is a POST and not a GET?

Comment: I suggest [reading the documentation](https://restsharp.dev/api/restsharp.html#constructor-restrequest-string-dataformat). Apparently you can create a `RestRequest` with a `DataFormat`. Perhaps using `DataFormat.None` would work?

Comment: It is a Post for sure.    It works on Postman

Comment: What would that call look like?

Comment: Postman is able to generate RestSharp code, click the "code" button/link/whatever it is and choose C#  RestSharp as the language

Comment: Eventually.  This is my own endpoint and right now I'm just testing it with no parameters.

Comment: That's a great idea.  I tried it but same result with that code.